# Creating lists with Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I'm attempting to follow this tutorial for creating lists of content:
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-lists

I've successfully created my custom content type for the list item, but when I expand the "New" tab in the Admin Dashboard, I don't have an option for "List".  I tried looking in the Module gallery, but was unable to find anything.

Any ideas?

TIA, -Jeremy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  The Orchard.Lists module was not installed.

Comment: Lists are rarely the right way of doing things. You should always consider Projector and/or Taxonomies first.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Thanks! This was a follow-up for an issue I had while exploring answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652967/building-a-site-with-orchard-cms.  Would you recommend not using the Lists approach listed there?

Comment: I'm also curious why you say that Lists are rarely the right way of doing things.  Perhaps, that is best presented as a separate question, or something that belongs on the Orchard discussion forum...

Comment: Lists is a feature that was built a long time ago. At the time, what we wanted to do was Projector but we didn't have the time to do it properly, but we needed some sort of generic way to create lists of items. We built Lists as the minimal feature that we could.
Now that Projector is out, I would personally almost never choose to use Lists. The only case where I would find it semi-legit is for real, unambiguous container types of relationships (such as file-folder or post-blog).

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Ah, that makes sense. Projector definitely looks way more powerful/flexible, so if it can do all that Lists can do and more, I'm all for using it. Thanks for the insight! :)